# Display string array with seperators using XAML in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking to print an array of strings with a separator between each string
example code block

```
string[] array;
string[] assignment = {"world","testing","array","hello"};
    for(int i =0 ; i>assignment.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = assignment[i];
}
```

XAML

```
        <controls:TappableCustomFontLabel
            x:Name="array"
            Text="{Binding array}"
            XAlign="Start"
            LineHeight="2.1"/>
```

XAML.CS

```
array.fillX();
```

I want to display each string in the array on a separate label, followed by a seperator
i.e

world

---

testing

---

array

---

hello

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want to display all the text in a single label, or each word in it's own label?

Comment: I want to display each string in the array on a separate label, followed by a seperator i.e

world
____
testing
____
array
_____
hello

Comment: You probably can't do that in XAML.  You'll need to iterate through your data and create an new Label for each element, then place them all in a layout.

Comment: Ah.. I'm having struggle.. I have a list of facilities that currently opens in an overlay.. I'm wanting to basically get rid of the overlay and have it place on the page.. The overlay has the layout of what I've explained here.  Is there anyway I can set up a Custom controller for printing a list of items in the structure explained ?   I'm fairly new to Xaml and Xamarin..

Comment: If you just want a list of items, use a ListView

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListView` or `CollectionView` and set your `ItemsSource` to `string[]` array. You can define `string[]` array in the **View** or **ViewModel**. It is recommended to define the array in the **ViewModel**.

Please note that larger arrays, lists or collections in **View.cs (Code behind)** has performance issues. Larger collections defined in View makes scrolling the `ListView` or `CollectionView` rough and uneven. Hence, scrolling lags while scrolling moderately larger `ListView` or `CollectionView`. Hence, define arrays, lists and collections in **ViewModel**.

**If you are using only View.cs**

```cs
public string[] Fruits
{
    get { return new string[] { "Mango", "Apple", "Pineapple", "Grapes", "Orange" }; }
}

public ListDemoPage  // Page Constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

**Or If you are using ViewModel:** (Skip this if you are not using ViewModel)

```
public class ListDemoPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string[] Fruits
    {
        get { return fruits; }
        set { fruits = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Fruits)); }
    }
    string[] fruits;

    public ListDemoPageViewModel()  // ViewModel Constructor
    {
        Fruits = new string[] { "Mango", "Apple", "Pineapple", "Grapes", "Orange" }; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Only If you are using ViewModel, set your Binding Context to instance of ViewModel class in your View.cs:** (Skip this if you are not using ViewModel)

```cs
ListDemoPageViewModel listDemoPageViewModel = new ListDemoPageViewModel();

public ListDemoPage  // Page Constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // set your Binding Context to instance of ViewModel class
    BindingContext = listDemoPageViewModel;
}
```

**And finally in your XAML**

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<!-- OR  You can use CollectionView -->

<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame BorderColor="Gray" Margin="5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```